# How do I get a macro loop skip a specific number of columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a macro that needs to loop through different tables in a spreadsheet, but since there are separate little tables in the sheet I want the macro to skip a specific number of columns to then look at another table.

Is there a way of getting the loop to do that?

---

Sorry for the lag in reply, basically I don't have much of a code, but the tables are formatted as follows:

```
Demographic                      |    |Demographic 2                     |    |Demographic 3
Table Title                      |    |Table Title                       |    |Table Title
[Blank]   | Heading 1 | Heading 2|    |[Blank]   | Heading 1 | Heading 2 |    |[Blank]
Demo 1    |   ###     |   ###    |    |Demo 1    |   ###     |   ###     |    |Demo 1
Demo 2    |   ###     |   ###    |    |Demo 2    |   ###     |   ###     |    |Demo 2
Demo 3    |   ###     |   ###    |    |Demo 3    |   ###     |   ###     |    |Demo 3
```

Hopefully that gives you the general gist of what the tables look like. But I need to copy the demographic and title, as well as the rest of the data within the tables. I've been told that the number of tables is fixed at the moment, but I'd like to future proof the code so that it doesn't matter how many tables are in there.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: The answer is: ***Yes, there is.***

Answer (score 0):

Use a test within the loop something like:

```
If Not <littleTable> then
    'do your stuff it's a big one
Else
    'skip your columns
End If
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change the way that I looked at the problem. I created a do-loop, that would cut and paste the table from one sheet to the other, and delete the columns afterwards to close the gaps. As long as I close the original excel sheet without saving, the original tables are left in tact. Seems to have solved the problems.

Thanks guys.